# How to fill generated Pivot Elements with data [templates]

Tags: windows-phone-7

Howdy,
I would like to generate in my application several PivotItems in a pivotelement. The generation is proceeding fine, however I don't know how I can apply a template to those Pivot Elements.

I thought I would need to use:

pivotItem.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)Ressources["KantinenUebersicht"];

But that is only producing an empty page.

My code in the ressource file looks the following:

**inserted my whole ressources File**

<.ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="KantinenTemplate">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" Margin="8,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding entfernung}" Margin="24,0,0,0" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="KantinenUebersicht">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock x:Name="KantinenName" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" Text="" RenderTransformOrigin="0.566,0.407" Margin="0,0,8,0" Height="55" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <TextBlock.Foreground>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}"/>
                        </TextBlock.Foreground>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="sdfsdf" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="8,59,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="196"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="lblGeoefsdfsdffnet" Height="40" Margin="208,59,8,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate></ResourceDictionary.>
```

Had to insert . in the first tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is correct.

In your question you have an extra "S" in "Resources" which could be the issue.

If I take the code from your question, I can add it to the page:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="KantinenUebersicht">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock x:Name="KantinenName" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" Text="" RenderTransformOrigin="0.566,0.407" Margin="0,0,8,0" Height="55" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                 <TextBlock.Foreground>
                  <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}"/>
                 </TextBlock.Foreground>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="lblEntfernung" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="8,59,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="196"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="lblGeoeffnet" Height="40" Margin="208,59,8,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

and then use it when creating a new item:

```
var newItem = new PivotItem { Header = "Added" };

newItem.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["KantinenUebersicht"];

MyPivot.Items.Add(newItem);
```

Works on my machine (emulator).

**Update:**
If you want to add the resource to a separate file you can do so like:

`ResourceDictionary.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
    <DataTemplate x:Key="KantinenUebersicht">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock x:Name="KantinenName" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeExtraLarge}" Text="" RenderTransformOrigin="0.566,0.407" Margin="0,0,8,0" Height="55" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                     <TextBlock.Foreground>
                      <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}"/>
                     </TextBlock.Foreground>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="lblEntfernung" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="8,59,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="196"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="lblGeoeffnet" Height="40" Margin="208,59,8,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then you must reference this external file in the page which wishes to use this file.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="\ResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Comment: actually the second 's' in ressources was an error which happend during typing it into the box. however what is missing is '<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>' but when I add that to my ressources file it returns an error

Comment: @theXs what is your "ressources file"? My code sample above is from MainPage.xaml.

Comment: My RessourceFile Name is till now "ResourceDictionary1.xaml". I just tried to debug and check what I can see under "this.resources" .. but it's an empty dictionary - which'll probably also mean why I do not see any output.

Comment: @theXs updated answer to show using the template specified in a separate file

Comment: Actually, I feel kinda stupid, but I cannot implement the <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources> in my XAML file. It says it must not have two root elements, however once I try to set it as an element like <phone:PhoneApplicationPage resources=...."> it'll crash...

Comment: @theXs I've just uploaded an example to http://cid-cc22250598bf7f04.office.live.com/self.aspx/Public/SO-4490457.zip